# Maybe in clojure

Tags: clojure

Trying to write a composed function in clojure that exits at the first nil value, (e.g something you'd do by chaining Maybes together in haskell) with the following:

```
(defn wrap [f] (fn [x] (if (nil? x) nil (f x))))

(defn maybe [arg & functs] ( (comp (reverse (map wrap functs))) arg))
```

So that I'd get, e.g.

```
(defn f1 [x] (+ x 1))

(maybe 1 f1 f1 ) => 3

(maybe nil f1 f1) => nil
```

Which is unfortunately giving me this:
ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  user/maybe (NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)

Can someone provide some help on what I'm doing wrong here? What's the idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: what does wrap do that (and x (f x )) not do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idiomatic way to do this is to use `some->`. See [the documentation](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/some-%3E) of this macro for more details.

Don't let that stop you from making your own, of course!

Comment: Note the resulting usage is slightly different; the some-> macro nicely pushes your result implicitly through the forms and is not composable whereas the maybe function requires actual functions but is composable.  e.g. `(some->> [1] (map inc))` but `(maybe [1] #(map inc %))`

Comment: @DaxFohl do you mean it's not composable because it's a macro? What's the difference between the two snippets in your comment?

Comment: @muhuk Yes it's not composable because it's a macro; if you wanted to at-runtime build your list of functions to execute in this way, you couldn't do it with `some->`.  The difference is that `(map inc)` is nicely shorter, but it's not an expression that will compile outside of the `some->` macro.

Comment: Got it. It doesn't really make `some->` itself non-composable though. Also you can still `(def f #(map inc %))` and then `(some->> [1] (f))` if you must.

Comment: @muhuk say you had `(defn runall [arg & functs] ((comp (reverse functs)) arg))`, just `maybe` without the `wrap`.  You could at-runtime choose between them `(let [myfunc (if whatever maybe runall)] (myfunc input f1 f2 f3))`. Can't do this with `some->`. That's what people mean when they say macros aren't composable.

Answer (score 5):

`comp` expects each function as an individual argument, but you're passing it a list of functions as a single argument.  To get around this, use `apply`.

```
(defn maybe [arg & functs] ( (apply comp (reverse (map wrap functs))) arg))
```

Answer (score 4):

There's always the `clojure.algo.monads` namespace with the `maybe-m` monad:

```
(with-monad maybe-m
  (defn adder [x]
    (let [f (fn [x] (+ x 1))]
      (domonad
        [a x
         b (f a)
         c (f b)]
       c))))

(adder 1)
=> 3 

(adder nil)
=> nil
```

Admittedly it might be a bit overkill for your requirements

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered, and I already put one up myself, but thought I'd add the following as I had a play with it using monads again, and this seemed a good question to post against.

Reading [this article on threading monads](http://overwatering.org/blog/2013/12/clojures-thread-for-monads/), I was able to come up with the following by extending the `m->` macro defined in the article to create a threaded maybe monad for simpler usage. TBH it doesn't come any simpler than just using `some->` but this was for personal curiosity.

OK, to start there's some one off boiler plate code to define, here (in case the article ever vanishes) is Giles' threaded monad definition:

```
(defn bind-monadic-expr-into-form [insert form]
  (list 'm-bind insert
        (if (seq? form)
          `(fn [bound#] (~(first form) bound# ~@(rest form)))
          `(fn [bound#] (~form bound#)))))

(defmacro m->
  ([m x]
   `(with-monad ~m ~x))
  ([m x form]
   `(with-monad ~m
                ~(bind-monadic-expr-into-form x form)))
  ([m x form & more]
   `(m-> ~m (m-> ~m ~x ~form) ~@more)))
```

Now with this, you can define a threaded maybe macro as

```
(defmacro maybe->
  ([x] `(m-> ~maybe-m ~x))
  ([x form] `(m-> ~maybe-m ~x ~form))
  ([x form & more] `(maybe-> (maybe-> ~x ~form) ~@more)))
```

And use it like:

```
(maybe-> 1 inc)
=> 2

(maybe-> [1 2] (#(map inc %)))
=> (2 3)

(defn f1 [x] (+ 1 x))
(maybe-> 1 f1 f1)
=> 3

(maybe-> 1 f1 ((constantly nil)) f1)
=> nil

(maybe-> {:a 1 :b 2} :c inc)
=> nil
```

There's absolutely no advantage in using this over `some->` in this context, but the `m->` monad does add some interesting abilities in being able to create a `fail->` macro as in the article I linked, which offers more than just "nil" as a return, giving you ability to differentiate the failure reason.