# Stacktrace and error monads in Clojure

Tags: error-handling, clojure, monads, stack-trace

I am not sure whether [error handling with monads](https://brehaut.net/blog/2011/error_monads) is considered as best practice for Clojure but it seems quite popular (however, I still see exceptions to be used also a lot). Monads seem more functional approach to error handling. However, I am missing the stacktrace when using error monads. Is there a way how to get stacktrace when using monads? Or what is the alternative in here?

Comment: When you are using monad, you wouldn't have an exception. When you don't have an exception, you wouldn't have a stacktrace. However you might be able to do something limited compared to stacktraces: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30812123/clojure-how-do-i-get-the-file-line-number-on-which-a-map-was-defined

Comment: If monads are considered a good practice for error handling I would expect that someone would already provide a good library for this purpose that makes this easy. Does anyone know about something like that?

Answer (score 0):

As muhuk says, you'd use a monad to avoid getting a stacktrace.

An article I discovered when answering [another SO recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30298662/690139) that relates to the one you linked is http://overwatering.org/blog/2013/12/clojures-thread-for-monads

It builds a `m->` threading monad, and gives example of using it to produce a `fail->` monad based on the work in the error monads article. It allows you to effectively return different error types during execution.

Comment: Thanks for more context. However, this doesn't answer my question. I don't understand why would I want to avoid something that I find useful. The stacktrace helps me a lot when investigating the problem. With monads I only see the error response but I am missing some more context related to the error, which I clearly see in the stacktrace. When running software in production I need to be able to trace the error and reproduce it. Maybe error monads are more functional but without good tracing support I don't see them very practical.

Comment: Potentially you could hook into the failure monad and print stacktrace for something that has failed. e.g in error-m monad, add a block around the `(if (has-failed? m) ...` with your own code to print out stacks etc. The article does say exceptions are left alone to "bypass the rest of the monadic behavior", so I'd expect genuine exceptions would still be thrown, is this not what you're seeing? If something fails with a known error (e.g. unknown user, resource not found), why would you need a stacktrace? that to me is the benefit of the error monad, as you still have the context of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Stack traces can be generated by saying `(Exception. "msg")` anywhere. I have been working on [Promenade](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/promenade) (see [documentation](https://cljdoc.org/d/promenade/)) that can combine exceptions and errors-as-values. You should take a look if that sounds like a potential solution.